# How to embed text to animated gif and save the gif?

Tags: ios, swift, gif, animated-gif

I am trying to save the gif with embedded text on it.

I tried adding subview on top of the gif and make the view transparent but I don't know how to add both files and save them as one.

```
@IBAction func shareAction(_ sender: Any) {
    let shareImage = generateMemedImage()

    let data = shareImage.pngData()! as NSData
    let nsdata:NSData = NSData(contentsOf: gifurl)!

    var array:[NSData] = []
    array.append(data)
    array.append(nsdata)

    let activityController =  UIActivityViewController(activityItems: array, applicationActivities: nil)
    present(activityController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    activityController.completionWithItemsHandler = {(activity, completed, items, error) in
        if (completed){
          //  self.save()
            self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}

func generateMemedImage() -> UIImage {
    // Render view to an image
    topToolbar.isHidden = true
    bottomToolBar.isHidden = true
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size)
    view.drawHierarchy(in: self.view.frame, afterScreenUpdates: true)
    let memedImage:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    topToolbar.isHidden = false
     bottomToolBar.isHidden = false

    return memedImage
}
```

Comment: Unclear what you're asking, since iOS has no built-in ability to save an animated GIF.

Comment: I am making a network request to download the gif and show it in my meme app and i can save the gif file with activity controller. But i want to add text to the gif and then save it.

Comment: Then you would need to generate an animated gif. It won’t happen by magic.

Comment: any suggestions or link How to do that?

Comment: No. You’d have to pull the gif apart into its frames, modify every frame, and assemble it all into a new animated gif. Not simple.

Comment: ok, Thanks for your help.I will try